# Update these dates in SQL Server to consecutive timestamps for each id?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have a table of IDs and dates. I need to turn the dates into datetimes, but each timestamp has to be unique within that ID. For example, if this is my table:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | 2020-03-21 |
| 0001 | 2020-03-21 |
| 0001 | 2020-03-21 |
| 0002 | 2020-03-21 |
| 0002 | 2020-03-21 |

then I need my output to look like:

| ID | Datetime |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | 2020-03-21 00:00:01 |
| 0001 | 2020-03-21 00:00:02 |
| 0001 | 2020-03-21 00:00:03 |
| 0002 | 2020-03-21 00:00:01 |
| 0002 | 2020-03-21 00:00:02 |

I'm pretty sure we can safely assume that no ID will have 86,400 entries on one day, so I shouldn't have to worry about the date rolling over by accident.

I'm thinking a cursor may be the answer, but I'm new to SQL and haven't had much luck figuring out how I'd use one for this. Here's what I tried so far, which didn't get me quite where I need to be:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [CID] ASC,[XDATE] ASC) AS RN
,[CID]
,[XDATE]
,dateadd(second, ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [CID] ASC,[XDATE] ASC))%86400),cast([XDATE] as datetime)) AS NEW_DATE -- 86400 sec in a day so need to mod ROW_NUMBER to prevent changing the date
FROM entryTable
```

This query applies the datetime addition consecutively, meaning it will occasionally happen that the time rolls over at midnight on the same day and ID as the last entry. This causes the entries to be out of order in our final database, as it sorts the data based on the timestamp, and anything showing up as post-midnight will then come before everything else that actually came first in our current database.

Comment: I would add a new column and put the row number in it rather than hacking around changing a date to a datetime when its not actually correct. And you are right, you definitely don't need a cursor.

Comment: `we can safely assume` - I don't think _we_ can, only _you_ know your data. And doesn't your _rolling past midnight_ indicate that you actually _do_ have some IDs with more than 86,400 rows per day? Have you considered going more granular than second if that's the case? Could you explain what you'd want the 86,401th row to say if you are trying to avoid duplicates and also making sure all the rows are presented in original sequence?

Comment: @AaronBertrand There are not IDs with more than 86,400 rows on one day. The sample code I gave does not solve the problem at all. The rolling past midnight issue happened because I wasn't resetting my starting time on each new ID. Going more granular would solve that issue, but it's not an option. There should never be an 86,401st row for one ID on one day.

Comment: I'm also curious where a requirement like `each timestamp has to be unique within that ID` possibly comes from. This is like "no two cars on the highway can go exactly the same speed."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you may not have a single ID with more 86,400 entries per day, it sounds like you have enough IDs with enough entries to go over 86,400 *total*. In order to reset the row numbers like you show in the question, you need to apply a `PARTITION` to the window function:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) OverallRN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CID, XDATE)
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER
  (PARTITION BY CID ORDER BY [XDATE]) AS RN
,[CID]
,[XDATE]
,dateadd(second, ROW_NUMBER() OVER
  (PARTITION BY CID ORDER BY [XDATE]),cast([XDATE] as datetime)) AS NEW_DATE
FROM dbo.entryTable;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2339784f6381fa83b1b6328c4f6c6b13)

If you still go over 86,400 entries for any given ID / day combination, you need to define what to do with 86,401+ because it certainly won't be `mod (%)` if you want to maintain the original sequence. Perhaps you need to go more granular than a second, like adding `ROW_NUMBER() * 100 milliseconds`. Although if those are the only two columns in the table, I don't know how you would know that anything is out of sequence.

Comment: This is excellent. And thank you very much for the example to go along, I found it quite helpful.

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
SELECT ID ,Date,
       concat(Date,' ',DATEADD(second, 
    CAST(43200000 * (CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) as int) / 4294967295.0 + 0.5) as int), 
    CAST('00:00:00' AS Time))) AS datetime
from entrytable
```

or better fit to your query

```
SELECT TOP 1000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [CID] ASC,[XDATE] ASC) AS RN
,[CID]
,[XDATE]
, concat(Date,' ',DATEADD(second, 
    CAST(43200000 * (CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) as int) / 4294967295.0 + 0.5) as int), 
    CAST('00:00:00' AS Time))) AS datetime
FROM entryTable
```

Comment: it provide random hour, time and seconds, hence it should makes it possible to get uniqueness

Comment: I have changed my answer that might fit better for this problem

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is still [not what the OP wants](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=07ffe77ef15c39f34943aa65e2ad8129). Neither `RAND()` nor `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM()` guarantee uniqueness or any kind of sequence, both of which the OP indicated they want. "Possible to get uniqueness" <> "guaranteed uniqueness."